# Setting "time" or DateInterval with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I inherited from a MySQL DB with a "time" column representing a "time in the week" in the range from "00:00:00" to "167:59:59" (24*7 = 168).

The corresponding ORM declaration is :

```
 * @var \DateTime $startTime
 * @ORM\Column(name="startTime", type="interval")
```

Apparently Doctrine always uses DateTime (not DateInterval) with PHP, probably to keep compatible with other DB engines.

**Problem is** : I fail to understand how to set those values, as they always turn to NULL on persist.

For instance :

```
$pWeek->setEndTime(new \DateTime('T'06:00:00'));
```

will set a DateTime in the Entity, but NULL in database.

I think the guys who designed this have set the data directly in DB, but since there's an ORM, I need to be able to set data with it.

Comment: The Type [interval](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html) appears not to exist. Do you have create your own Type ? Maybe the problem comes from here.

Answer (score 1):

That's odd, but in the end that code was... **working**.

No idea how I came to see it fail, I guess it was likely just a cache thing.

Thanks